# Jquery offset top and position fixed not consistent in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple custom script with floating `#sidebar`. I want the sidebar to keep floating until before the `#footer`so that it doesn't overlap with the footer.

I have been able to achieve this in all browsers except IE7 and older ones.

You can view a demo here:
http://butlimous.hostingsiteforfree.com/test.html

This is code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="ie7-
detected">
<![endif]-->

<![if (!IE)|(gte IE 8)]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<![endif]>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function () {   

 if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#sidebar').css('position','fixed');
    $('#sidebar').css('top','0');

     if($('#ie7-detected').length == 1) {
       $('#sidebar').css('marginLeft','6px');
    }
    else {
       $('#sidebar').css('marginLeft','508px');
    }       
 }

 else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 100) {
      $('#sidebar').css('position','');
      $('#sidebar').css('top','');
      $('#sidebar').css('marginLeft','');  
 }
 
 if (($('#footer').offset().top - $('#sidebar').offset().top <= 612)) {

 var sidebar_pos = 612 - parseInt($('#footer').offset().top - $('#sidebar').offset().top);
 $('#sidebar').css('top', '-' + sidebar_pos + 'px');

 }
 });
});
</script>

<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">

<div style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;">

<div id="header" style="height:100px;border:1px solid #000000;clear:both;">
</div>

<div id="sidebar" style="float:right;height:600px;border:1px solid #000000;width:490px;">
 </div>

<div class="post" style="height:300px;width:500px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;margin-bottom:10px;">
</div>

<div class="post" style="height:300px;width:500px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;margin-bottom:10px;">
</div>

<div class="post" style="height:300px;width:500px;float:left;border:1px solid #000000;margin-bottom:10px;">
</div>

<div id="footer" style="height:100px;border:1px solid #000000;clear:both;">
</div>

</div>
```

In IE7 the floating is not consistent and sometimes overlaps with the footer and sometimes doesn't.

Another issue is that at a certain pixel when scrolling, the `#sidebar` gets totally off the screen.

Keep in mind that the document height is not fixed as some pages may have different number of posts than other pages not like the demo i made.

Comment: i know but unfortunately old versions are still used worldwide :(

Comment: this may help you
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: They *are* used worldwide, but IE7's market share worldwide is less than 0.5% (http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-september-2013/), so probably represents a disproportionate amount of effort to support. Plus, anyone using that old a browser *will* be used to everything being just a tiny bit broken. Even google discontinued support for it two years ago: http://googledocs.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html